# How do you stop Mathematica from evaluating a sum?

Tags: evaluation, summation

A concentration $A(i,j)$ varies over i,j.

I'd like to include the summation of $A(i,j)$ in my *Mathematica* expressions, but it evaluates the sum

```
 In[1]:  Sum[Aij, {i, imax}, {j, jmax}]
 Out[1]: Aij imax jmax
```

i.e. *Mathematica* is treating all A(i,j) values as equal, so that $\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^M A(i,j) = NMA$. This isn't the case, how do I stop it evaluating the sum?

My system also includes terms like $\sum_{j=1}^N\sum_{i=1}^M A(i,j)u(i,j)$, which I also don't know how to write in *Mathematica*.

```
 In[1]:  Sum[Aij uij, {i, imax}, {j, jmax}]
 Out[1]: Aij imax jmax
```

Comment: `Aij` is the symbol *Aij*. Try somthing like `A[i,j]`. Also, don't use uppercase initials in symbols - might clash with a built-in...

Comment: Oh great, simple! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In addition, if you want to keep a sum in unevaluated form (to perform symbolic manipulations on it), you should check out `Inactive`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add formatting:

```
Format[A[x_, y_]] := Subscript[A, ToString[x] <> ToString[y]]

Sum[A[i, j], {i, 1, imax}, {j, 1, jmax}]
```

[image]